# What is alternative of create_proc_entry()

Tags: linux-kernel, procfs

As `create_proc_entry` function is deprecated, what is its replacement?
I was trying to create a simple proc entry using `create_proc_entry` but got the this error:

> error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’

I grepped `create_proc_entry` in proc_fs.h but didn't find it there. Is there something that I'm missing or there's alternative to do this?

Comment: You should try what is described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516021/proc-create-example-for-kernel-module

Answer (score 25):

The newer functions are named `proc_*`. You can see their declarations in [`include/linux/proc_fs.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/proc_fs.h).

In particular, `proc_create` creates a proc entry. You can check out the implementation of the other (quite useful) functions in the source file at [`fs/proc/generic.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/generic.c). You may be particularly interested in [`proc_mkdir`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/generic.c#L434) and [`proc_create_data`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/generic.c#L441).

---

Note to future visitors: Please keep the date of this post in mind. The links are to the master branch of Linux, which could change over time. If you need the interface for an older version, you can find the equivalent location for a previous commit. If you want the latest version, the suggestions in this answer could have become outdated.