# error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver

Kernel version : 3.13.0-32-generic

When i am building the module getting the error

> make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build
>   M=/home/wipro/Downloads/proc modules make[1]: Entering directory
>   `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'   CC [M] 
>   /home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.o /home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.c:
>   In function ‘proc_win_init’: /home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.c:21:5:
>   error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’
>   [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>        if ((file = create_proc_entry("rel_time", 0666, parent)) == NULL) {
>        ^ /home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.c:21:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>        if ((file = create_proc_entry("rel_time", 0666, parent)) == NULL) {
>                  ^ /home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.c:25:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>        file->read_proc = time_read;
>            ^ /home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.c:26:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>        file->write_proc = time_write;
>            ^ /home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.c:32:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>        link->uid = 0;
>            ^ /home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.c:33:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>        link->gid = 100;
>            ^ cc1: some warnings being treated as errors make[2]: *** [/home/wipro/Downloads/proc/proc.o] Error 1 make[1]: ***
>   [_module_/home/wipro/Downloads/proc] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving
>   directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic' make: ***
>   [default] Error 2

How to remove the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: implicit declaration of function 'create\_proc\_read\_entry' \[-Werror=implicit-function-declaration\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746461/error-implicit-declaration-of-function-create-proc-read-entry-werror-implic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`create_proc_entry` has been removed since 3.10 kernel version. Alternative is to use `proc_create`. See that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565381/what-is-alternative-of-create-proc-entry) for more info.