# proc_dir_entry structure linux 3.13

Tags: c, linux-kernel

i am using proc_dir_entry in linux 3.13 but i got this error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" in this lines of code :

```
  struct proc_dir_entry *proc = proc_create("hello_proc", 0, NULL, &hello_proc_fops);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "name : %s\n",proc->name);
```

it seem like the compile doesnt recognize the data structure

Answer (score 2):

The internals of `struct proc_dir_entry` were made opaque in Linux kernel 3.10 by [commit 59d8053f1e16904d54ed7469d4b36801ea6b8f2c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/include/linux/proc_fs.h?id=59d8053f1e16904d54ed7469d4b36801ea6b8f2c), so all you get now is a pointer to an incomplete type.

The "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" error is due to the expression `proc->name` due to `struct proc_dir_entry` being incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,
what is the solution  , that mean i musn't use this data structure ?

Comment: Is there any way to work with variable like "name" , "next", "parent" or   "subdir"   ? all of those are useful

Comment: @Waheni All you get to work with is what is defined by `#include <linux/proc_fs.h>`, which doesn't provide access to any of the things you mention above.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8521197/3209523) may be you forgot to put include statements

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>
```