# User Permission check on ioctl command

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ioctl

I am implementing char driver ( Linux) and there are certain IOCTL commands are there in my driver which needs to be only executed by ADMIN.

My question is how can I check user permission under my ioctl command implementation and restrict unprivileged user from accessing IOCTL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bool capable(int cap)` function, which returns *true* if user has capability requested. Possible values of *cap* are listed in kernel sources at `include/uapi/linux/capability.h` (macros started with *CAP_*).

As you can see, there are many admin-like capabilities. Choose one which seems fit better for you task. Or just take *CAP_SYS_ADMIN*.

Answer (score 2):

#### Restrict by Write Permission

You can restrict certain ioctl commands if the device is opened read-only. To implement this, given the first parameter to the `ioctl` function, `struct file *file`, test if `file->f_mode` has `FMODE_WRITE` bit set.

```
if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE))
        return -EACCES;
```

Set the permissions so that only a particular user or group has write permissions for the device. This could be useful in a scenario where certain users should be able to control a device, by opening it in read-write mode, while other users can only read the device and get status by opening it in read-only mode.

A user might also choose to `open()` the device with mode `O_RDONLY`, if the user only wants to read the device while ensuring he doesn't modify it.

#### Restrict by Capabilities

You could restrict certain ioctl commands to only be permitted if the user has a specified [capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) (`CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is likely suitable).

```
if (!capable(CAP_SYS_ADMIN))
        return -EACCES;
```