# How to call function in kernel module from user space on ARM64?

Tags: linux, arm64

In x86, one of the answer should be hook(intercept) system call. But in arm64, I haven't seen any example showing how to do it on arm platform. It seems not a good idea for arm platform. Are there any other method to make it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use ioctl() to manipulate my kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264384/how-do-i-use-ioctl-to-manipulate-my-kernel-module)

Comment: What sort of kernel function are you talking about ? Normal transitioning from user space to kernel is to call `svc` instruction and SVC Interrupt Handler pass control to some function in Kernel space